# How do I flip the line orders of a document with 500+ lines?

Tags: script, notepad

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

should become

```
Line 5
Line 4
Line 3
Line 2
Line 1
```

I need a notepad script to do this.

Comment: Notepad is not scriptable, is it?

Answer (score 7):

If you have [Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) installed you can use

```
perl -e 'print reverse <> ' filename > newfile
```

As in

```
$ cat file.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
$ perl -e 'print reverse <>' file.txt > new.txt
$ cat new.txt
line 5
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 1
```

(its the same on Windows but use `type` instead of `cat` and use double-quotes (") in the `perl` command.)

You have tagged your question "notepad" and mentioned "notepad" in the text. If you want a solution using "notepad++", you should edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

This is a three step process in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) using TextFX.

1. Select the entire document (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) (or the section you want to be reversed), and from the TextFX menu, select `TextFX Tools -> Insert Line Numbers`.
2. From the TextFX menu, make sure that `TextFX Tools -> +Sort ascending` is unchecked and then select `TextFX Tools -> Sort lines case sensitive (at column)`.  This will reverse the order of the lines.
3. From the TextFX menu, select `TextFX Tools -> Delete Line Numbers or First Word`, and you're done.

The Notepad app that ships with Windows is pretty much useless.  There are many alternatives, but I prefer Notepad++.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad, unless you mean some other than the one that comes with Windows OS, is not scriptable. Were you to use Vim, it would be simply

```
:g/^/m0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try tac which reverses line by line

```
tac filename
```